# Need to insert the Upload count in the database and in table

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting the following details in my form. I need to loop through the fields which have "attachment" in the name and add the count to the table, and also the values in the new table.

```
ATTACHMENT   C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp\neotmp3230094756217875313.tmp
ATTACHMENT2  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp\neotmp4341408903737742616.tmp
ATTACHMENT3  C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp\neotmp2809169853442728277.tmp
```

I am trying to do a loop over the form fields, but I am lost in between, and am unsure where to proceed.

```
<CFLOOP collection="#structform#" item="whichField">
    <cfif FindNoCase('attachment',whichField)>
       <cfset total = len(whichField)>
       <cfoutput>#total#</cfoutput><br><br>
    </cfif>
    <CFOUTPUT>#whichField# = #structform[whichField]#</CFOUTPUT><br>
</CFLOOP>
```

Comment: Not sure your question is completely clear - are these formfields file inputs or text inputs?  What 'total' are you trying to calculate; the size of the files? Or the length of the filepaths?

Comment: solved t like the below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<CFLOOP collection="#structform#" item="whichField">
    <cfif FindNoCase('attachment',whichField)>
        <cfset lstvalue = ListAppend(lstvalue,whichField)>
    </cfif>
    </CFLOOP>
    <cfset total = ListLen(lstvalue)>
    <cfif (len(total) AND total EQ 1) AND (Evaluate(lstvalue) EQ '')>
        <cfset total = 0>
    </cfif>
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do, but this is _definitely_ not the way to do it.

Comment: I am lost right around `(Evaluate(lstvalue) EQ '')` . what is that trying to do?

Comment: `(Evaluate(lstvalue) EQ '')` one of my field will be always be one which has name of Attachment, so it has a value it will new to null or it is empty it will be null, so that checks that code, i had added it with and condition so it should both conditions and then proceed ahead, else if multiple values comes in the **lstvalue**, it will throw an error. Like this `<cfif (len(total) AND total EQ 1) AND (Evaluate(lstvalue) EQ '')>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not certain I've understood what's going on, so this might need tweaking/changing to make it work as needed, but this is without doubt a better approach:

```
<cfset Total = 0 />
<cfloop collection=#StructForm# item="FieldName" >
    <cfif findNoCase('attachment',FieldName) AND len(StructForm[FieldName]) >
        <cfset ++Total />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: total is always going to be 1

Comment: Well then it's probably named wrong, but replacing the inner cfset with `<cfset Total=1 />` `<cfbreak/>` will do that.

Comment: Make sure you output the total variable outside of the loop